# Is there any way to figure out if your outdoor faucet is frost free?

Tags: faucet, outdoor

I just bought a house last spring, and now is time to clean up outside for winter.

Thing is, I don't know if my outdoor faucet is frostfree or not.

Is there a reliable way to tell if a faucet is frostfree?

Here is my faucet
[image]

Comment: Basement, crawl space, or slab?

Comment: weve got a heated basement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you turn the water off does it dribble for a few seconds like a 6 or 8" pipe back in the wall. The absolute way would be to pull the valve stem but this requires turning the water off.  Looking at your faucet it is a frost free. The valve seat is usually inside the wall with the supply pipe, this is how I have seen and plumbed them. Makes a hell of a mess when they break but if the home is heated that almost never happens. Some go into the crawl space these were put in by some sick puppies in my area they freeze under the house to fix swimming in ice mud. Note keep your valves open on that Y or the water gets stuck and will break the pipe with a good freeze.

Comment: I would remove that Y and put one of those styrofoam covers over it. https://www.grainger.com/product/48H485?gclid=CjwKCAiAiarfBRASEiwAw1tYv-n5LXItVh32I31Ve8YxAQz_jskOuxShaxp3DPWrx2ZP3Jn88U6LMhoC7tkQAvD_BwE&cm_mmc=PPC:+Google+PLA&ef_id=CjwKCAiAiarfBRASEiwAw1tYv-n5LXItVh32I31Ve8YxAQz_jskOuxShaxp3DPWrx2ZP3Jn88U6LMhoC7tkQAvD_BwE:G:s&s_kwcid=AL!2966!3!264922907937!!!g!437998010149!

Comment: Yes I agree on removing the y but if a frost free inside a heated area. When temps get into the low teens maybe single digits things change. Been there and the only problem I have had was we dropped the house temp below livable. It was empty and for sale and it was on a wall that had high wind . Made a hell of a mess but lucky it was in a wall on a slab so a bit of cleanup sheetrock and insulation and it was back to like new. Note the pipe in that wall that broke was over a foot above the point maybe 18" above the point of entry on a brick wall, so the Styrofoam cover would have been useless